# Sorting of User Defined Vector

Tags: java, list, sorting, vector

In my java program i have created a Vector of user defined type
`Vector<PolledData> poll=null;`. The Vector is of type of instance of class `PolledData`.
I need to sort the Vector poll, I tried `Collections.sort(poll);`,but it didn't work.

Is there a any way to sort the vector poll?

Comment: Note also that you shouldn't be using `Vector`s in new code because the class [is considered obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated). Use some other list implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`) if you can.

Comment: post your user defined class and code if your expecting us to point out correction.

Comment: I Got the Answer,Thank you

Comment: @AravindhanK Please post your answer (or mark an answer as solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is:

```
Collections.sort(poll, new Comparator<PolledData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final PolledData object1, final PolledData object2) {
            return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
        }
       } );
```

Now the elements in my Vector poll is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Comparable / Compactor for pojo which are being stored in vector.